# Openlayers3 clicking outside feature deselects all features

Tags: openlayers-3

I would like to continue using the default toggle options of the interaction.Select, so the user can only have one feature selected at a time. However, when a user clicks outside of a feature, I do not want it to remove the currently selected feature. Is there a way to achieve this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem with the following...

```
var select = new ol.interaction.Select({
            style: vm.selectedFeatureStyle,
            condition: function (event) {
                if (event.type === 'singleclick') {
                    return vm.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, function () {
                        return true;
                    });
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```